# How to get all rows based on single id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a parent/child relationship structure.

There are 3 types of entities:

1. Actual Location (type=1)
2. Sub Group (type=10)
3. Head Group (type=100)

Example structure

```
id  parent  name                        type
28  0       Head Group                  100
10  28      --Location 1                1
12  28      --Location 2                1
16  28      --Location 3                1
17  28      --Location 4                1
19  28      --Location 5                1
29  28      --Location 6                1
8   28      -Sub Group 1                10
11  8       --Sub Group 1 Location 1    1
30  28      -Sub Group 2                10
13  30      --Sub Group 2 Location 1    1
14  30      --Sub Group 2 Location 2    1
15  30      --Sub Group 2 Location 3    1
```

I want to be able to select all rows if 1d 28 (Head Group) is passed in.

I've tried to create a statement but I think this is beyond me.  ANy help would be appreciated...

```
SELECT CGroup.id, 
     CGroup.parent, 
     CGroup.name, 
     CGroup.type
FROM Customer AS CGroup 
INNER JOIN Customer AS CSubGroup
  ON CSubGroup.parent_id = CGroup.id
WHERE CGroup.parent_id=28
```

Comment: What is the result which you want to see from your query?

Comment: the key question here is, will there be an upper limit on the number of levels of hierarchy/inheritance or must it generalize to n levels? If you are sure that it's never deeper than 3 levels, for example, the query is easy enough. If n levels you need some code or a stored procedure.

Comment: there is only two levels at the moment and that is all I am trying to cater to

Answer (score 1):

You're making it too complicated. Keep it simple. Simple queries usually execute faster and have less bugs.

```php
// first get all subgroups under the main group
subGroupIds = fetchField('
  select group_concat(id)
  from CGroup
  where parent = 28
    and type = 10
')

// then get everything
results = fetchRows('
  select *
  from CGroup
  where parent = 28
    or parent in (subGroupIds)
')
```

If you really want to do it "properly", I recommend implementing a [Nested Set tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).

Comment: If I give you a +1 will you let me tell you that its `fewer bugs` rather than `less`.  dont worry, I know i'm an asshat. ;)

Comment: @paqogomez feel free to edit my answer to fix that :p

Comment: I'm not that much of an asshat. :)  Great answer.